# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'namaproduct' cannot be null

Tags: mysql

I have some problem with this request. When I click submit, I'm getting an error like this:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'namaproduct' cannot be null
```

This is my controller's function

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $product = new Product;
    $product -> namaproduct = $request->namaproduct;
    //...........................
    $product->save();
    return redirect()->route('kontak')->with('alert-success','Data berhasil diTAMBAH!');
}
```

This is my kontak.blade

```
//..................
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>

                <th>Nama Product</th>
                <th>Deskripsi</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Ukuran</th>
                <th>Warna</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Stok</th>
                <th>Harga Normal</th>
                <th>Harga Diskon</th>
                <th>Aksi</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @php $no = 1; @endphp
            @foreach($product as $produk)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $produk->namaproduct }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $produk->descriptionproduct }}</td>
                    //.....................................
```

This is my kontak_create.blade.php

```
//.............
<form action="{{ route('kontak.store') }}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Nama Product:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product" name="product" required>
            </div>

//..................
```

Why can't I insert into the database?

Comment: Your input name is "product" but on the request you put "namaproduct" so just change it.

Comment: thanks.. is solved.. (y)

Answer (score 0):

That means that your column `namaproduct` is not nullable, meaning you're submitting an empty value for that key.

Edit: After your post of the dd, I can see that you are missing a value on `namaproduct`.

You can simplify the method by doing: `Product::create($request->all);`, but the error will remain, as you're lacking the key => value of `namaproduct => "something"`

Place this in your controller in order to view what you're submitting.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
     dd($request->all());
     // menggunakan elequent untuk menyimpan ke database

     $product = new Product;

     $product->namaproduct = $request->namaproduct;
     ...........................
     $product->save();

     return redirect()->route('kontak')->with('alert-success','Data berhasil diTAMBAH!');
}
```

Comment: when i dd ,, this is the result 

array:10 [▼
  "_token" => "DWHAN5bcnZ7ADDSYJP3ro2qQvOCrQhCIYlMRb7zs"
  "product" => "lkdnvlkdfn"
  "deskripsi" => "<p>lknvdlkfnvkfb</p>"
  "currency" => "lkbvdkfbvkjfb"
  "ukuran" => "lkbvdfkbvj"
  "warna" => "bvdkjfbvk"
  "type" => "lkvbdvkj"
  "stok" => "kbvdfkljbv"
  "normal" => "klbvskjdbv"
  "diskon" => "klbvfaekjbfvklaw"
]

Comment: how to fix it ? let the data show on table when i submit

Comment: @BimoAnugrah you are not submitting value for namaproduct.

Answer (score 0):

The message from the MySQL is pretty obvious ;) Data from the request is empty. Your table schema does not allow empty `namaproduct`. Try using default value:

```
$product -> namaproduct = !empty($request->namaproduct) ? $request->namaproduct : 'default value';
```

Another approach is to throw some kind of error to the user, so he/she will know that the attribute is required.